# Change a property of an object in a pipe (rxjs)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an object `Person`.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I'm getting a stream of `Persons` using an observable.

```
getPersons(): Observable<Person> {
  return this.myService.getPerons.subscribe(data);
}
```

I want to apply a modification on the age field and keep the name as it is

```
person.age = person.age + 2;
```

Example:

> Original stream: {name: 'John doe', age: 40}.
>
> After applying pipe: {name. 'John doe', age: 42}

I guess that `.subscribe(data).pipe(map(e => ...))`is not the solution here and I'm looking for an alternative to apply on the pipe

Comment: whats the problem with pipe and map approach?

Comment: Why not modify the values inside of `subscribe`? `subscribe(data => { // modify data here })`

Comment: @ShlokNangia I'm not sure but I think that map will convert an object to a field. It will return a new stream of ages. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @MikeS. That was an example. The real object I have contains a lot of properties and I only want to modify one. Is there a way I can copy all of them and change the one I want ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do it with `map` operator in the service. Try the following

myService

```js
getPerons(): Observable<Person> {
  this.http.get('url').pipe(map(response => ({...response, age: response.age + 2})));
}
```

And you could subscribe as usual in the component

```js
this.myService.getPerons.subscribe(data => { this.persons = data });
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xxxsy. I'm not sure I'm doing map correctly. The result is a number and not an object

Comment: You are only returning the number, not an object

map(data => ({...data, age: data.age + 2}))

Comment: @ahmedkh I've included the edit from Alexander. I was accidentally returning only the age instead of the object.

Answer (score 3):

`map` also is a solution, and you can also use just `tap` or just modify in the `subscribe`. But you need to use them before `subscribe`

```
.pipe(tap(e => /**/)).subscribe(data) -> this can omit the return data
.pipe(map(e => /**/)).subscribe(data) -> this must return data
```

Comment: If it is object, you can change it

Comment: true, sorry, I'm wrong, Apologies for my angry comment

Comment: Tap is a very bad approach to handle this scenario and it should be marked as such. Tap is a sideeffect in your pipe. You only can mutate your object within the tap. A similar effect would be achieved if you mutate the object from another place in your code (not within your pipe).
You can mutate objects but you have to be very conscious about it. This can cause changes to other functions/places where your object is being used. The more safe approach would be to use immutability and transform your object into a new one.

Comment: You are right if the programmer uses functional approach, but who knows

Comment: It's more about clean code and maintainability than functional programming. Small codes in study might work this way but in mid to large applications you should absolutely avoid side effects.

Comment: I don't think so. Immutability is not related to the clean code in my opinion. If you come from OO language, the sense of immutability is lost, but you can still provide clean code

Comment: Regarding to Wikipedia (not the most serious source but the fastest one): In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object (unchangeable[1] object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.
That is a quote from: Java Concurrency in Practice. Addison Wesley Professional, 2006

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *tap* operator to do this job

```
.subscribe(data).pipe(tap(e => ...))
```

Comment: NOT use "tap" to change a response, tap NOT change the response, tap is for log the response or caché, but else not more

Comment: He asked for an alternative, and I said 'you can use' not 'you should use'.

Comment: true, sorry, I'm wrong (I not delete my comment because i think always we can learn about a bad answer)

Comment: tap not dedicated to change obj.prop